# svelte forms de-structuring binding

Tags: forms, binding, svelte, destructuring

My code is working, but I just wonder if there's a tidier way of achieving what I've done with some de-structuring. Essentially I've started of from the code here:

https://svelte.dev/repl/2441993f8d9946aa894bf07a8a8f9b4f?version=3.52.0

and nest the array within an object and added a delete button like so:

```
<script>
        let f={
        "name" : "", "type" : "",
        "values":[{ "label": "", "start": "", "end": "" },
                            { "label": "", "start": "", "end": "" },
                            { "label": "", "start": "", "end": "" }]
        }; 

        // let { name, type, values } = f
        
        const addField = () => {f.values = [...f.values, {label: '', start: '', end: ''}]}; 
        const removeField = (v, i) => {f.values = f.values.filter((e, id) => id!=i)}
    </script>

    <input type="text" bind:value={f.name} placeholder="name"/>
    <input type="text" bind:value={f.type} placeholder="type"/>

    {#each f.values as v, i}
    <div>
        <input id={i} type="text" bind:value={f.values[i].start} placeholder="start"/>
        <input id={i} type="text" bind:value={f.values[i].end} placeholder="end"/>
        <input id={i} type="text" bind:value={f.values[i].label} placeholder="label"/>
        <input id={i} type="button" value="X" on:click={removeField(v, i)}>
    </div>
    {/each}

    <button on:click|preventDefault={addField}>Add</button>

    <button on:click={() => console.log(f.values)}>Save</button>

    <pre>
     {JSON.stringify(f, null, 2)}
    </pre>
```

As far as I've tested it it appears to work, but I just wonder if there's easier ways to bind nested values of the object, so the code looks a little cleaner rather than referencing 'f.' everywhere.

When I've tried referencing the de-structured values the binding gets lost - I suppose this is normal behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `#each` the `v` variable will be the current item which you can use directly:

```html
{#each values as v, i}
    <div>
        <input type="text" bind:value={v.start} placeholder="start"/>
        <input type="text" bind:value={v.end} placeholder="end"/>
        <input type="text" bind:value={v.label} placeholder="label"/>
        <input type="button" value="X" on:click={removeField(v, i)}>
    </div>
{/each}
```

For the script part, there would be certain ugly workarounds with re-assignments or dummy assignments, but the cleanest solution would probably be to extract everything about the values into a separate component, e.g.

```html
<!-- Values.svelte -->
<script>
    export let values;

    const addField = () => {values = [...values, {label: '', start: '', end: ''}]};
    const removeField = item => {values = values.filter(x => x != item)}
</script>

{#each values as v, i}
    <div>
        <input type="text" bind:value={v.start} placeholder="start"/>
        <input type="text" bind:value={v.end} placeholder="end"/>
        <input type="text" bind:value={v.label} placeholder="label"/>
        <input type="button" value="X" on:click={removeField(v)}>
    </div>
{/each}

<button on:click|preventDefault={addField}>Add</button>
```

Which then can be added as:

```html
<Values bind:values={f.values} />
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/cd9a528ea7af40449bff780f405b5664?version=3.52.0)

(By the way, `id` attributes are not allowed to start with numbers and have to be unique in the entire page.)

Comment: This make a lot of sense - thanks for the explanation

Comment: How do I make the values of start, end & label unique?  At the moment when I post the form I only get the last value of start, end & label rather than an array of values

Comment: A common convention is to add the index somewhere the field name, e.g. `name="values[{i}].start"`, you then have to convert that back to an array of objects on the server. Alternatively, send a JSON object and deserialize the JSON on the server, which gives you a hierarchical data structure for free. To do that, you would probably have to use `preventDefault` on the `submit` event and send the data manually.

Comment: If you have the same name multiple times, you should be able to read that field as an array as well. Depends on the server being used. Please search StackOverflow for relevant questions and post a separate question if you still have issues.